# A more functional way to create tuples from two arrays

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I've created a function that gets all integers from `1` to `n` and then combines with the same sequence to create a sequence of tuples of all combinations. So passing it the integer `2` would give you `[(1,1);(1,2);(2,1);(2,2)]`:

```
let allTuplesUntil x =
    let primary = seq { 1 .. x }
    let secondary = seq { 1 .. x }
    [for x in primary do
     for y in secondary do
     yield (x,y)]
```

This implementations works, but it uses an inner and outer for loop, similar to what I would do in `c#`.

Could this be achieved in a more idiomatic functional way? Would a more functional way typically be more desirable or is this acceptable in a functional language because of its brevity and clarity?

I'm relatively new to `f#` and looking for some feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These loops are part of what's called *computation expression*, which is quite idiomatic to F#. It's just made to look like familiar loops. I can't see any problem with your code being written in this way. If what you want is to get rid of the loops, you could hide them in functions:

```
let cartesianProduct xs ys = 
     xs |> Seq.collect (fun x -> ys |> Seq.map (fun y -> x, y))

cartesianProduct [1;2;3] ['a';'b';'c']

val it : seq<int * char> = seq [(1, 'a'); (1, 'b'); (1, 'c'); (2, 'a'); ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, just because there is a `for` doesn't mean its not functional. In this example you go over each element and yield a new element that will turn into a new element of a new immutable list. Such feature is also named "List Comprehension" and part of languages like Haskell. Imperative would be to loop over a list and mutate the list.

Second, remember that other functions like `map`, `fold`, `filter` also just loop over each element, like a `for` expression. They are just less powerful than a `for` loop.

Third, even if it would be "not 100% functional". Who cares? Code should be easily readable and understandable. The intention of two `for` loops is easy to understand.

Fourth, the equivalent function of the `for` expression is usually the `bind` or in this case the `Seq.collect` function. You also could write, this code.

```
[for x in primary do
 for y in secondary do
 yield (x,y)]
```

Like this:

```
primary |> Seq.collect (fun x ->
secondary |> Seq.collect (fun y ->
    [x,y]
))
```

I prefer the `for` loops for readability!